# How can I change the way I see the page behind when I open a Twitter Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am opening a modal but when I do this the page behind the modal goes very dark. Can someone explain how I can change this. For example how could I make it so there's just a very light shading on the background.

I also notice that when I click the background then my modal disappears. Is there a way I can remove this functionality. I would like my modal to only go away when the user clicks submit or close on the modal itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your looking for is http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals modal backdrop static to disable closing on background click.

Also for the backdrop darkness adjust the

```
.modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't I have to set up a DIV for the modal backdrop?

Comment: No, twitter javascript makes the modal backdrop, you don't need DIV for that.

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking to keep the backdrop behind the modal *but* make the backdrop completely transparent, set a transparent background-color instead of changing the opacity:

```
.modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop.fade.in { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
```

This allows you to be able to click off of your modal and have your modal close while not actually seeing the backdrop.

Comment: You made my day. Up voted for you. It perfectly works with static backdrop.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bs 3, you can use data-backdrop="false" attribute in your link so you dont have to modify your base bootstrap files.

It's in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage)