# Bootstrap css without affecting the background

Tags: css, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap css, it is possible to display a modal dialog, but I want to be able to make it modal so the UI behind doesn't respond (without having the dark black background shown).

There seems to be no options that allow me to do this on the `$("#selector").modal()` function.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172739 for help or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000011 - They are duplicates of what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **modal** will constitute of the modal container itself and anoter `div` that does the "dark" thing all over the background.
Simply use the Chrome inspect element to see its (the overlay dark div) class, and then override the background color to be transparent.
 You will now have a transparent div on 100% of the screen behind the modal, so nothing will respond but there will be no "darkness" to the background.

**EDIT**
the class of this div is usually `.modal-backdrop`, so you can apply your css to this class.

Comment: The OP is a dupe. Please do not feed the duplication.